# How plot more that 1000 dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I have exactly `1686` dictionary keys. Each of these keys contains a list of labels. There are `41` labels and each key generally has from `2` to `x` labels. I would like to plot a kind of venn-diagram to see which keys have common labels. How could I do it?
The keys are too many to use a library like `matplotlib-venn`.

Comment: With that many keys and without more information about how they are linked together, an interactive force-directed graph is probably one of few tools to obtain more insight. See e.g. [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8). Optionally, you concentrate on one or a few important labels and then explore further.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying it